# Converting multiple emojis into a single character

Tags: javascript

‍❤️‍ is created combining  (\uD83D\uDC69), ❤️‍ (\u200D\u2764\uFE0F\u200D) and another  (\uD83D\uDC69) in a single string: \uD83D\uDC69\u200D\u2764\uFE0F\u200D\uD83D\uDC69

How do I convert this String:

`\uD83D\uDC69\u200D\u2764\uFE0F\u200D\uD83D\uDC69`

to its character representation ‍❤️‍?

This is not a duplicate question. The link to the duplicate is for urls. This is about generating an emoji character. I don't see any relationship between those two. This has nothing to do with escaping a uri. The question is how to decode a zero-width joiner.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It's not about escaping a uri.

Comment: If you have a string which literally contains "backslash u d 8 3 d" etc, and you want to turn that into the character that's supposed to represent, then what you want is to *decode a string with escaped unicode*. It doesn't matter that that string represents a URL or an emoji or whatever else.

Comment: If you still think those solutions don't apply, show us a sample where you try to apply that solution to your situation and how that turned out and why it doesn't apply.

Comment: Pedantic note: the `\u200D`s are the Joiners that make the whole thing come together, they aren't part of the heart.

Comment: My question is about decoding a zero-width joiner into a single character and not about decoding escaped characters in a uri. Checkout https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner

Comment: OK, so… have you ***tried*** it? `JSON.parse('"\\uD83D\\uDC69\\u200D\\u2764\\uFE0F\\u200D\\uD83D\\uDC69"')` results in  ‍❤️‍.

Comment: That works. Please post it as the answer and remove the "duplicate" note. Thanks.

Comment: While your solution works, it doesn't work with this: JSON.parse('"\\u1f469\\u200d\\u1f469\\u200d\\u1f466"'). That results in multiple characters. I'm running this in Chrome.

Comment: "Post it as answer" – That *is* the answer *in the duplicate*. Hence, *duplicate.*  If you have a specific question about a specific sequence which doesn't work in that schema, ask about that specifically.